# In Laravel Pagination how to add first page and last page?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-8

In Laravel 8 pagination how to show less number of pages and also how to add "First Page" and "Last Page"

Now in Laravel when we have more data, it will show the pagination like this:
[image: Laravel 8 Pagination]

But I want my pagination to be like the images given below:

[image: Desired Pagination Sample]

Or

[image: Desired Pagination Sample]

Comment: either use simplePaginate or customize your pagination view https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Comment: I know that but my question is that we do not have a built-in and customized pagination in Laravel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To customizing the pagination view, run below command in console

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

in /resources/views/vendor/pagination/bootstrap-4.blade.php add bellow code.

```
<ul class="pagination">
    @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
        <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.first')">
            <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        </li>
    @else
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="{{ \Request::url() }}" rel="prev" aria-label="@lang('pagination.first')">&laquo;</a>
        </li>
    @endif

    ...

    @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="{{ \Request::url().'?page='.$paginator->lastPage() }}" rel="last" aria-label="@lang('pagination.last')">&raquo;</a>
        </li>
    @else
        <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.last')">
            <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        </li>
    @endif
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

class MyPresenter extends Illuminate\Pagination\BootstrapPresenter {

    public function render()
    {
        if ($this->currentPage == 1) {
            $content = $this->getPageRange(1, $this->currentPage + 2); 
        }
        else if ($this->currentPage >= $this->lastPage) {
            $content = $this->getPageRange($this->currentPage - 2, $this->lastPage); 
        }
        else {
            $content = $this->getPageRange($this->currentPage - 1, $this->currentPage + 1); 
        }

        return $this->getFirst().$this->getPrevious('&lsaquo;').$content.$this->getNext('&rsaquo;').$this->getLast();
    }

    public function getFirst($text = '&laquo;')
    {
        if ($this->currentPage <= 1)
        {
            return $this->getDisabledTextWrapper($text);
        }
        else
        {
            $url = $this->paginator->getUrl(1);
            return $this->getPageLinkWrapper($url, $text);
        }
    }

    public function getLast($text = '&raquo;')
    {
        if ($this->currentPage >= $this->lastPage)
        {
            return $this->getDisabledTextWrapper($text);
        }
        else
        {
            $url = $this->paginator->getUrl($this->lastPage);

            return $this->getPageLinkWrapper($url, $text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MyPresenter class name, and in your custom view   <ul class="pagination">
    <?php echo with(new MyPresenter($paginator))->render(); ?>
</ul>